# Dockerizing a Nodejs application - Error in copying files from local to WORKDIR

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to Dockerize my Nodejs application which uses Firebase cloud functions.

This is what my project directory looks like -

[image]

When running without using Docker, I follow the following steps to start the server -

1. `cd functions`
2. `yarn serve` - this script is present in `functions/package.json`

Now I want to Dockerize this application, the Dockerfile which I created looks like this -

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /api

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./api

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

When I build an image using this and run the container, execution fails (I think it's because of missing files in the container)

Command used to build image -
`docker build -t <my-image-name> ../functions`

When I look into container file system I do not see the exact file structure which I have on my machine.

What are all the changes needed in Dockerfile?

Comment: `COPY . ./api` copies all the files of `functions` to `/api/api` in the container because you added `WORKDIR /api` ([documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir)). You can replace it with `COPY . .` and it should be working fine.

Comment: Won't `COPY . .` copy files only from `functions` to `api` in my container?

Comment: Because you specified `functions` as PATH in the build command you will only be able to copy file from the functions directory. If you would try to copy for example the firebase.json file during the build process it wouldn't be able to build. Which files do you need in your container?

Comment: @joelthegraf I need all the files in the same way as I have it locally

Comment: Could you tell me the error message you receive when running the container so I can get a better overview on what your application depends on?

Comment: @joelthegraf the error message is specific to firebase emulator which my backend runs on. this depends on firebase.json present in the root of the application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245693/discussion-between-vaibhav-deep-and-joelthegraf).